# How to implement a character device with blocking?

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, kernel-module

I need to create a character device that reads data from a circular buffer. I would like to avoid frequent polling on the user side. This means when the user demands more data than the buffer currently contains, the user thread should block until enough data is written. In general case the thread should periodically wake up, read a data portion from the buffer filling the user-provided buffer and continue sleeping until the latter buffer is full.

Can you suggest proper kernel synchronization primitives to achieve this behavior? Should I use in-kernel critical sections?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** Actually I have meant a typical synchronization scheme that is used in such (I believe pretty typical) cases rather than primitives.

**UPDATE 2** For the moment I see the following scheme. The device can be opened by only one user (others are rejected). When user calls `read()`  the handling routine checks the number of available bytes in the circular buffer. If there's enough, those are copied to the user buffer and removed from the circular buffer. Otherwise the routine is blocked using a conditional variable. The (interrupt-driven) routine that generates data checks whether a user is blocked on a reading call. If yes, it puts the bytes directly into the user buffer, and when it's full it signals to wake up the conditional variable. When no reading call is in-progress, the data generating routine adds the data to the circular buffer.

Comment: "Can you suggest proper kernel synchronization primitives to achieve this behavior?" - Wait queues, mutexes, splinlocks, etc. If you are looking for example, you may find it in the book [Linux Driver Development](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch06.pdf). Otherwise please provide the code you already have: we may **add** blocking part to your code, but we wouldn't write the **whole** code for you.

Comment: If the buffer is circular.. how can it not contain enough data?

Comment: Say we have N-byte buffer. Now the user requests to read N+1 bytes. Returning only the data currently written in the buffer will cause multiple subsequent polling (assuming the bytes are written slower than user can read and process). So it makes sense to block the user until the required number of bytes have been retrieved and written.

Comment: "Actually I have meant a typical synchronization scheme that is used in such (I believe pretty typical) cases rather than primitives." - "Typical" synchronization could use one of `wait_event_*` function. But which exact function to use very **depends** on your **actual case**. Have you read the book (actual, the chapter) I refer in my previous comment? It contains an example of blocking `read` function with detailed description.

Comment: I think the similar case is mentioned here (top-half IRQ handler wakes up a read-handler): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809140/how-correctly-wake-up-process-inside-interrupt-handlers